# "live" Ubuntu from a CD

Tags: system-installation

Never used Linux and very cautious. I read somewhere that Ubuntu can be run from a CD.  But I have not found any instruction on the website.
I'd like to download and write a CD on this machine to run it on another which is not internet connected and has no USB.

Comment: Quite an easy site to find - http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: From the official Ubuntu website: [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)

Comment: You can NOT run vanilla Ubuntu from a CD. DVD is the minimum from Ubuntu. From a CD... start with the minimal install (=40 Mb-ish) and build the system up from that.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: Ubuntu won't fit on the CD, it is too large. You need a DVD to burn current Ubuntu image. After you have burned Ubuntu DVD, just insert it into DVD drive and restart your computer. After a minute you will be seeing some sort of welcome screen with two buttons: *Install Ubuntu* and *Try Ubuntu*. Choose the second one and that is it. See [Ubuntu Documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) for more details.

**PS**

If your BIOS is set to boot from Hard Disk first (unlikely, but possible) then You should enter the *boot menu* by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> or other one (depends on your motherboard). In the *boot menu*, choose CD/DVD item to boot the computer from Ubuntu DVD.

Comment: Sometimes a bios is programmed to boot from HDD first and if failed it boots from cd. In this case hit the esc button repeatly from the moment you turn on your pc until you get boot options.

Comment: F10 on hp, f8 on Asus

Comment: Thank you all.  I'll do that, but I'll have to use a different machine since the oldie only has CD.  I don't think DVD was invented in 1997!

Comment: @PoorJohn it is very unlikely that Ubuntu would even start on the machine from 1997.